# SonarQube anasysis task changes the output of the build

Tags: c#, tfs, build, sonarqube-scan

While setting an CI environment, in our buld definition we have a task "**Prepare the SonarQube analysis**" and another task that builds the solution.

The task that builds the solution is based on dotnet CLI (**dotnet build**) and it receives 3 parameters: the configuration (release), the sln file and the output(the output folder where the binaries will be saved). The solution contains 2 project: a .net standard class library and a .net framework 4.6.2 class library.

To test the CI, I've created a branch and removed the CLS compliant attribute from the .net framework project, hoping that I will make the build to fail (I'm treating all warnings as errors, my rule set file is included in the project and it contains among other rules, the rule **CA1014**, about the CLS compliance).

My surprise was that the build will fail in TFS only if I disable the SonarQube analysis step. With this step enabled, the build passes and even if I'm seeing in the log this warning, the build ends with success.

Do any of you know how to fix this issue?

Also, if this is not the proper site to ask this, please suggest me and I will move the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read from this [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) and it states that:

> The "begin" step will modify your build like this:
>
> - all existing code analyzers that are referenced by your projects will be disabled and only analyzers from SonarQube plugins will be
>     executed
> - the active CodeAnalysisRuleSet will be updated to match the SonarQube quality profile
> - WarningsAsErrors will be turned off
>
> If your build process cannot tolerate these changes we recommend
>   creating a second build job for SonarQube analysis.

So this is why during the build with this task enabled, some of my rules are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Check the reason from case [Treat Warnings as Errors using SonarQube Analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052454/treat-warnings-as-errors-using-sonarqube-analysis):

> Practically speaking, there is little point of using the SonarQube
>   scanner with `TreatWarningsAsErrors=true`, because when the build
>   breaks, there will be no build results from our analyzers, the end
>   step will not be executed and no issues will be pushed on SonarQube.
>   If there are no issues from your builds, there is no reason to use
>   SonarQube. In addition, with `TreatWarningsAsErrors=true` you will be
>   forced to fix everything beforehand, or live with failing builds for
>   long time, which I would not advise.
>
> SonarQube allows you to fix your existing and new issues [little by
>   little](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Fixing+the+Water+Leak)
>   and avoid having failed builds for long time because of warnings. You
>   can rely on the quality gates for feedback about your code quality and
>   even, if you insist, fail the builds when the quality gate does not
>   pass (note that on large projects this might affect the build time).
>
> If your builds are required to fail because of compiler warnings (note
>   that SonarQube does not collect the standard compiler warnings, just
>   the results of the Roslyn analyzers), I would recommend creating a
>   separate build job for analysis. This way you will have the best of
>   both worlds - issue tracking in SonarQube and failing builds because
>   of compiler warnings.

Comment: But the thing is that locally, I have StyleCop analyzer configured with it's ruleset and I want my build to pass first this set of rules. So if there is a developer that ignores the error from the IDE and created a pull request, I want the build to fail.

Comment: @BudaGavril You may try to clone the Visual Studio Build task out of the SonarQube tasks.

Comment: So what I've noticed is that if I use msbuild task together with the sonarqube analyse task, if the code is breaking StyleCop rules, the build passes, but if the code breaks ManagedCodeAnalysis rules, the build failes... I don't understand why... From the sonarqube task log I've seen this: Installing required Roslyn analyzers... Maybe this has to do something with the stylecop analyzer?

Comment: check my answer